# How to fix Swift's inaccurate debug-descriptions for doubles?

Tags: swift, double, points, floating

I just got my app to run recently; while testing I noticed an inaccuracy when I added values of `0.1` for multiple times to another double.

So I started researching and testing on doubles and (their) inaccuracy. I came to the result that the `debugDescription`-property of doubles returns other values than the assigned values. Relate to this snippet to try and see, what I mean:
`let double = 0.1
print(double.debugDescription)

// result: 0.10000000000000001`

Is there a nice solution or workaround the make doubles more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

What you see *is* the stored value. When you print it and you get 0.1, this is because swift helpfully rounds the number so it looks nicer. The debug description will likely give you the exact value stored. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic for an introduction of how swift stores numbers.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent this behavior/use other classes? Because adding around hundred `0.1`-values makes the result very inaccurate with time.